# NativeAdExpressView inside RecyclerView

Tags: android, admob, android-recyclerview, native-ads

I have a RecyclerView with following Adapter class. Now I want to implement NativeAdExpressView inside the RecyclerView. Every 11th element of the RecyclerView should be an Ad. Which is the best method to add Ads using the below Adapter class?

```
public class SearchResultAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<SearchResultAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
private List<Searchresult> resultList;
private Context context;

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView name, course, department, bloodgroup;
    private ImageView pro_image;
    private RelativeLayout relativeLayout;

    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
        course = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.course);
        department =(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.department);
        bloodgroup = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.bloodgroup);
        pro_image = (de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
        relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.parentLayout);
    }
}

public SearchResultAdapter(List<Searchresult> resultList) {
    this.resultList = resultList;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    final View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.search_result_row, parent, false);
    context = parent.getContext();
    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final Searchresult result = resultList.get(position);
    holder.name.setText(result.getName());
    holder.course.setText(result.getCourse() + ", Semester : " + result.getSemester());
    holder.department.setText(result.getDepartment());
    holder.bloodgroup.setText(result.getBloodGroup());
    String img_url=result.getProImage();
    Picasso.with(context).load(img_url).resize(750,750).centerCrop().into(holder.pro_image);
    holder.relativeLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //ButtonClickAction
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return resultList.size();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will Guide you

[Native Express RecyclerView sample](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/tree/master/advanced/NativeExpressRecyclerViewExample)

[Video tutorial for Native Express in a RecyclerView](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LZCZSeFTvyk&index=11&list=PLOU2XLYxmsIKX0pUJV3uqp6N3NeHwHh0c)